# SharePoint Online :Hyperlink Issue : Import hyperlink from Spreadsheet to SharePoint Import Spreadsheet web part

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Spreadsheet with columns as below

[image]

**Scenario**

I am trying to import this spreadsheet to create a SharePoint list using the import spreadsheet app which duplicates the columns and data of existing spreadsheet. As you know Hyperlink is not supported in this its importing the Column as plain text. Is there any other method to import this data as the spreadsheet has 3500 records.

[image]
Final output should be something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create SharePoint list items from Excel rows

**Please the following steps:**

1. Upload the **.excel file** to the SharePoint Document Library

[image]

2. Creat a **new list**

[image]

3. Create a **MS Flow**

[image]

4. **Save** and **Test** this Flow

[image]

Comment: Hello @EchoDu_MSFT Sorry i might not be specific with my requirement and Hyperlink column is type of column and it has alternative text in one column as tag station and url is the link that should go in to Site URL and i have my list already created with Stations sites and url now the task is to move the content from sites to alternative text and url to site url as shown in the figure

Comment: I can move the content directly from spread sheet to a list but hyperlink column has two variables like Site url and alternative text

Comment: Hi, AIM4DREAM. It is not yet possible to realize your design, you can only manually add alternate text for each hyperlink. If there is any better solution later, I will share with you as soon as possible. Have a nice day!